# Debian 9 stretch can't adjust laptop monitor brightness with fn keys

Tags: debian, laptop, brightness

Laptop Model: HP Pavilion dv6 2170ee

I could change monitor brightness by **fn + f7 / f8** keys in Debian 7 wheezy.

But since I installed Debian 9 stretch, seemingly, these keys do not work. Even in Mate Power Manager there's no slider to change brightness. I searched a bit. Like these pages:

> [Fn keys can't adjust brightness MATE desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537137/fn-keys-cant-adjust-brightness-mate-desktop)
>
> [Brightness fn key shortcut doesn't work on ASUS laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop)

When I run `acpi_listen` and press fn + f7 / f8 keys, I get:

```
khosrow@hpx:~$ acpi_listen
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
```

So I guess the keys work, but the brightness doesn't change. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you make an upgrade from Debian 7 --> 9 or did you clean installed it? Also see: https://askubuntu.com/a/859480

Comment: I did a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your /etc/default/grub file? I have a potential solution:

In /etc/default/grub, change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=native pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi="
```

That enabled my ability to change the backlight with my Fn keys, with some side effects. Read more about that here: [Need help configuring ASUS G75VW NVidia Debian 9 brightness: How do I get my Fn keys to change the brightness AND keep the slider in the top right?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421871/need-help-configuring-asus-g75vw-nvidia-debian-9-brightness-how-do-i-get-my-fn)

Comment: link doesn't work anymore